# Making a PHP dropdown box pull data from an SQL database

Tags: php, html, sql, xampp

so I've been trying to get this working for a few days now and I am completely lost. I've tried following a few of the answers on here but I can't seem to figure out what I need to change to adapt it to my database.

There have been complex and simple solutions I have seen, but what I am attempting at the minute is this:

...

```
    <?php
    echo "";

    define('DB_USER', 'username');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 'username_test');

    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

?>
<?php 
    public function get_data()
    {
       $mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't    connect".mysqli_connect_error());
       $sql="SELECT Staff_Surname, Staff_Forename FROM users";
       $result=$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
          while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
          {
            echo "<option value=\"".$row["Staff_Surname"]."\"  selected>".$row["Staff_Forename"]."</option>";
          }
     }  
?>

<html>

<body>
<select name="abc" id="xyz">
    <?php  get_data(); ?>
</select>


</body>

</html>
```

...

which just results in a bunch of errors when I try to run it in a browser. I am using Microsoft Expression Web 4 and XAMPP.

This is a screenshot of the SQL database I just need to pull the forename and surname into a dropdown box:
[SQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32nTH.png)

Any help you guys can offer would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Sorry, in the preview it looked like it showed what the error was. When I try to run the code in a browser I get this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbJsR.png)

Comment: What is the error message? Why do you connect again in the function - you have an connection already, pass it into the function as parameter...

Comment: (you should have only  one `selected` in the `option` tag, but this is not the main problem)

Comment: there might be a `"` in the `$row["Staff_Surname"]`

Comment: posting the generated HTML would also be helpful

Comment: _"just results in a bunch of errors"_ - Thought about sharing them with us? It makes it a bit easier for us to help if we know what you need help _with_.

Comment: Lars and Magnus edited to show the error I get when I send it to the browser.

Draz so I should drop the "Staff_Forename"? and I tried removing all spaces, should I try taking out the speech marks?

Comment: Sorry Lars I forgot to reply to the second part of your comment. I have two connections because the first PHP is my code which I have tried and works to connect me. The second PHP and the select code beneath it is from a solution I was trying to follow here on Stack Overflow. I thought you were supposed to open a connection to the database each time you use it and close it again afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

> **Notice**:  Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in **index.php** on line **17**
>   
>   **Warning**:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in **index.php** on line **17**
>   
>   **Warning**:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in **index.php** on line **19**
>   
>   **Warning**:  get_data(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in **index.php** on line **19**

Change

```
$mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't    connect".mysqli_connect_error());
```

to

```
$mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't    connect".mysqli_connect_error());
```

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file in **index.php** on line **15**

Change

```
public function get_data()
```

to

```
function get_data()
```

These changes should take care of all the errors you are receiving.

Comment: I tried making the changes you suggested but it still doesn't want to play.

Comment: @Dave - are you sure that you have the right username and password for your database? Using your updated code I get the expected output.

Comment: @stealthhyninja I am quite sure I'm using the right username and password, I have even tried reverting to root and blank. But I can't seem to get it to work. Whats more, even the test page I made before where it was able to connect is coming up with an error now too. There must be something wrong with my XAMPP or something. Will post some screenshots in my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code with @stealthyninja edits:

```
    <?php
    echo "";

    define('DB_USER', 'username');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 'username_test');

    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

?>
<?php 
    function get_data()
    {
       $mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die("Couldn't connect".mysqli_connect_error());
       $sql= "SELECT Staff_Surname, Staff_Forename FROM users";
       $result= $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
          while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
          {
            echo "<option value=\"".$row["Staff_Surname"]."\"selected>".$row["Staff_Forename"]."</option>";
          }
     }  
?>

<html>

<body>
<select name="abc" id="xyz">
    <?php get_data(); ?>
</select>


</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:

- Issues connecting to MySQL. First the usernames and passwords are
  here: [login info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRgBt.png)
- The XAMPP control panel: [XAMPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At3B6.png)
- The testcode that worked previously: [Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjpCO.png)
- And the error it now presents: [Registration Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSYTU.png)

I don't think I have changed anything from when it worked before. I built the Registration page following a tutorial in the book *"PHP and MySQL for Dynamic Web Sites fifth edition"* by Larry Ullman.